# What's the Best Way To Namespace AMD Modules?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, modernizr, amd, js-amd

Modernizr was written using AMD definitions, which is nice since that's what I'm using for my current project and can pull in Modernizr dependencies when I need them. Problem is, the Modernizr modules all expect a flat folder heirarchy, but I've moved the files into my project like so: lib > modernizr

What's the best way to change the paths on the dependencies in the Modernizr definitions? Is this something I can handle with RequireJS? I could obviously do it by hand, but I want to be able to easily pull in Modernizr updates in the future and not have to manually update the paths every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this would be a good idea. From the [docs](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing):

> The reason we recommend placing Modernizr in the head is two-fold: the HTML5 Shiv (that enables HTML5 elements in IE) must execute before the `<body>`, and if you’re using any of the CSS classes that Modernizr adds, you’ll want to prevent a FOUC.

Anyway, you can specify the full paths in a [requirejs.config](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config):

```
// in your main
require.config({
    paths: {
        "modernizr": "lib/modernizr"
    }
});

//in your module
define(["modernizr"], function (modernizr) {
});
```

Comment: Just for some future poor soul's sake, I adhered to their recommendations and removed the Modernizr source, and instead loaded in the Modernizr generated file that I created from their site. I wasn't really getting anything extra by having the modules, since I was just loading in the Modernizr module anyway and not the individual modules themselves.